# std::map - C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to fill a `std::map`, but I am getting 2 compiler errors, and I don't know what the cause is.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> dirFull;
dirFull["no"] = "north";
dirFull["so"] = "south";
dirFull["ea"] = "east";
dirFull["we"] = "west";
dirFull["nw"] = "north-west";
dirFull["ne"] = "north-east";
dirFull["sw"] = "south-west";
dirFull["se"] = "south-east";
```

Those are the errors:

```
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
       dirFull["no"] = "north";
       ^
error: size of array has non-integer type 'const char[3]'
       dirFull["no"] = "north";
               ^~~~
```

---

I have also tried this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> dirFull = { 
    {"no", "north"}, {"so", "south"},
    {"ea", "east"}, {"we", "west"},
    {"ne", "north-east"}, {"nw", "north-west"}, 
    {"se", "south-east"}, {"sw","south-west"} };
```

This results in a complete different type of error:

```
error: non-aggregate type 'std::map<std::string, std::string>' (aka '...') cannot be initialized with an initializer list 
std::map<std::string, std::string> dirFull = {
                                   ^         ~
```

Comment: @TonyD I forgot to add, I am using `using namespace std;`

Comment: Then it's likely that there's something else critical you've omitted.  Please include the verbatim, unabridged code as a minimal complete example.

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`?

Comment: There is no error in this. See this -> http://ideone.com/RpqIhx

Comment: @BrianCain , I believe I've included everything relevant to the question. Also, these definitions are in my file.h file. Should they be in a file.cc file? Does it matter?

Comment: Ahhhh... I bet you haven't got the `dirFull[...] = ...;` statements inside a function, right?  You can only perform those assignments inside a function.  You can, however, use `map<string, string> dirFull = { {"no", "north"}, {"so", "south"} , ... };` with C++11 onwards.

Comment: @TonyD no, they're exactly as I pasted above... I guess that would be the issue!

Comment: @TonyD if I do it as you suggested (and in file.h), will functions within my file.cc be able to use the map?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're trying to execute statements at file scope.  Define these assignments in a function and you will not get these errors anymore.

If you want to populate this `map` during static initialization time, you can use `boost::assign` or <strike>`constexpr`</strike> initialization syntax to do that.

```
//requires c++11:
const map <string,string> dirFull = {
    {"no",   "north"},
    {"so",   "south"},
    {"ea",   "east"},
    {"we",   "west"},
    {"nw",   "north-west"},
    {"ne",   "north-east"},
    {"sw",   "south-west"},
    {"se",   "south-east"},
};
```

Comment: If I get the error `non-aggregate type 'map<string, string>' (aka 'map<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >, basic_string<char,
      char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >') cannot be initialized with an initializer list` does this mean I am not using c++11 ?

Comment: @user5759490 probalby, check your compiler options

Comment: Yes, it does, make sure you add `-std=c++11` (`g++` or `clang++`)